# Is there any API to access iOS's back-to-app button programatically?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm wondering if there is an API in Apple SDK that allows using "back-to-app" button in your code.

I'm pretty sure it can be done using tap imitation however it doesn't seem like a fully-legit solution.

[image: iOS status bar with "return" button]

Comment: What do you mean "Allows using 'back-to-app' button in your code"? Why do you need to alter this button? This is an apple-device defined feature and doesn't have anything to do with your app specifically. In the same regard, there are functions in the `AppDelegate` to determine when a user leaves, comes back, etc with your app.

Comment: @impression7vx, I would like to have an opportunity to switch between two apps. I'm not asking how to alter it, I just want to simulate its behavior or probably call this button action itself.

Comment: Apple is pretty clear that one app cannot affect another app. Personally, I wouldn't even remotely get near this. Use 1 app ;)